# What is difference between WebSockets and Socket.io?

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io

**Scenario**: I'm new to JavaScript (have experience C/C++/Java), and working on a React UI with NodeJS server wherein the server will get updates on the displayed data at specific intervals (say 5 secs). The server is supposed to push the data to React UI to update the displayed data quickly.

**Contenders**: I came across 2 JS libraries Websockets (is lib a right term for websocket?) and Socket.io to achieve this. To me they both appear same.

**Did I Google?**: Yes, but with my lack of knowledge of JS, I couldn't understand the difference.

**Problem**: What is the difference between these 2 libs (libs?) and how can I decide which one is more suitable here?

Comment: Can you please explain why is it off-topic?

Comment: What's this "Websockets" library you speak of? Is that a extension on VanillaJS?

Comment: Yeah, sure. Stackoverflow already made the effort explaining it in the help-center. Just have a look there https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: [Web Sockets](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/web-sockets.html#network) isn't a library, it's a specification for a browser feature, which [is implemented](https://caniuse.com/#feat=websockets) in all vaguely up-to-date major desktop browsers (and many mobile browsers).

Comment: Websocket is Normal Javascript API supported in almost all browser, Socket.io is JS library which internally use Websocket API

Comment: @baao: Dont want to be rude, but there are lots of similar questions with huge upvotes? https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=difference+between 
Can you please explain further?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder :Thanks a lot! Can you please add your comments as answers, so that I can accept.

Comment: @Nemani: Thanks a lot! Can you please add your comments as answers, so that I can accept.

Comment: @Cerbrus: T.J.Crowder's comment has link to Web Socket above.

Comment: I think you'd be best off just deleting the question. :-) (Esp. as my comment above doesn't really address what socket.io is. But [their website](https://socket.io/) does.)

Comment: @Tingya: I know. My comment wasn't serious, it was a joke.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Nah, I wont mind losing points if I get the answer. (However, I'm still not getting why this is off topic :( )

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Scenario: I'm new to JavaScript (have experience C/C++/Java), and working on a React UI with NodeJS server wherein the server will get updates on the displayed data at specific intervals (say 5 secs). The server is supposed to push the data to React UI to update the displayed data asap.

This is how I would do it.

> Contenders: I came across 2 JS libraries Websockets (is lib a right term for websocket?) and Socket.io to achieve this. To me they both appear same.

In short, I am aware of two different ways of communicating between the server and client: WEBSOCKET and SERVER-SENT EVENTS (SSE). They are slightly different so it would be highly advisable to Google both options to find out which would suit you better.

Socket.io is essentially a library to assist with the creation/management of websockets. Imagine it to be your .NET Framework when you could have written a system yourself in C instead.

> Did I Google?: Yes, but with my lack of knowledge of JS, I couldn't understand the difference.

Here are some links that can help you:

**SSE:**

1. https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events

**WEBSOCKET**

1. https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications

**COMPARISON**

1. https://www.google.com.au/search?safe=off&ei=MmNLWuGkLsHQ0AS87J_4Bw&q=websocket+vs+sse&oq=websocket+vs+sse

> Problem: So can you please help me understand the difference between
>   these 2 libs (libs?) and help me decide which one is more suitable
>   here?

As I have mentioned before, you have technically only mentioned one package library (socket.io) which manages the websockets via their API. I would assume the other method would be to do it manually using the native JavaScript method. It is up to you which one you choose and you'll surely find that there are advantages and disadvantages with both.

Comment: Thank you, just the answer I was looking for!

Comment: No worries, I know it's hard starting in any language. All the best.

Comment: **Please don't put all of your text in bold**, there's no good reason for it. Leave the font choices for the site to the site.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks for the feedback. I'll keep it in mind (relatively new to stackoverflow posting).

Comment: Just because it's off-topic, I believe it doesn't mean it doesn't deserve an answer.

Comment: Sure, but not on Stack Overflow, as it's not on-topic on this website.

Comment: @Cerbrus: can you please explain why this is off topic, there are so many diff between questions here